# Simulate active session on a website with python

Tags: python, url, connection, simulate

I'm looking for a way to simulate an active session on a website using Python. What I mean by that, is I want to create a software, which makes the website think that an actual user with an actual browser has the website open. I've found urllib3 and it's request.urlopen methon, but it seems that this only reads the content provided from url and closes the connection. Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

You can try simulate browser requests to get necessary cookies for authentication. Google Chrome Dev Tools and requests python lib will do the job.

Some websites have another way to handle sessions, but I believe the majority is using cookies set through post requests.